# Listview adding items from otherActivity

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm trying to fetch the data from the other activity and adding it to the listview which is in my main acitivity

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> fetchList= new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imglist);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                R.layout.custom_textview,R.id.listtext,
                myStringList );
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null ) {

            fetchList=  getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data");
            for(int i = 0 ; i < fetchList.size() ; i++) {
                filepath = fetchList.get(i);
                imgfilename=filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                myStringList.add(imgfilename);
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
   }
```

Now my problem is when I fetch the data and the items for the first time it adds perfectly but when I go and add it for the second time the previously added items are no more seen(ie..the old items are deleted and new items are added)

I want to add the newly items to the existing items and I'm not storing any kind of listview items data at present.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: one option is to make your list static so you will have that for entire app....or you can save you data in savedinstance state and get it back

Comment: create some static data holder, that will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
   public static ArrayList fetchList= new ArrayList();

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imglist);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.custom_textview,R.id.listtext,
            myStringList );
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
ArrayList<String> fetchList= new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imglist);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.custom_textview,R.id.listtext,
            myStringList );
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null ) {

        //get some flag to notify adpter refresh
        if(getIntent().getBoolean("refresh"))
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

}
   }

in second activity add data to static list

```
MainActivity.fetchList.add(your data);
```

and pass bundle with flag to first activity on back

Answer (score 0):

put those two lines out of loop ..

```
 lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```